# POST 500 Internal Server Error -- PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

### A strange problem that is making me puzzled

this code was working perfectly at localhost

And after uploading to server i found this : 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

and some other times it shows : POST $link 500 (Internal Server Error)

Wordpress !

**AJAX Code:**

```
function fetch_select(val) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'test2.php',
        data: {
            get_option:val
        },
        success: function (response) {
            $('.restaurnat').html(response);
        }
    });
}
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['get_option'])) {
        if (!empty($_POST['get_option']) && $_POST['get_option'] != 0) {
            global $wpdb;
            $rests = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM Cities WHERE ID = $_POST['get_option']", ARRAY_A);
            if (!empty($rests)) {
                foreach ($rests as $rest) {
                    echo "<option value='" . $rest['ID'] . "'>" . $rest['res'] . "</option>";
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo "<option value=''> --- Choose Country or City First --- </option>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class='container'>
    <h1 class='text-center'>Choosing requests</h1>
    <form class='text-center form-horizontal' style='padding:10px;max-width:400px;margin:auto;' action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method='POST'>
        <h1 class="text-center" style='font-size:3.9em;margin:40px 0;font-weight:bold;'>Choose City or Country</h1>
        <select name='city' onchange='fetch_select(this.value)'>
            <option value=''>--- Choosing City or Country ---</option>
            <?php
                global $wpdb;              
                $q = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT City_Name, ID FROM Cities ORDER BY ID ASC", ARRAY_A);
                if (!empty($q)) {
                    foreach ($q as $city) {?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $city['ID']; ?>"><?php echo $city['City_Name']; ?></option> 
                    <?php 
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "<div class='container'><div class='alert alert-warning'><p class='lead'>There is no city or Country at the database</p></div></div>";
                }
            ?>
        </select>
        <br />
        <h1 class="text-center" style='font-size:3.9em;margin:40px 0;font-weight:bold;'>Choose restaurant</h1>
        <select name='restaurant' class='restaurnat'>
            <option value=''>--- Choose Country or City first ---</option>
        </select>
        <input type='submit' value='Order now' class='btn btn-lg btn-primary' style='margin:10px;'/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: When you tried this on localhost, did you try AJAX the WordPress way or simple PHP?

Comment: I tried it with the simple PHP way ( PDO )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solved.

The problem Was that : I forgot to do :

```
require_once('wp-config.php');
```

At the beginning of the page !

Answer (score 2):

You need to target `admin-ajax.php` to handle AJAX requets in WordPres.

```
function fetch_select(val) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        data: {
            get_option:val
        },
        success: function (response) {
            $('.restaurnat').html(response);
        }
    });
}
```

[This answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/190993/why-use-admin-ajax-php-and-how-does-it-work) might help you as well, regarding WordPress AJAX.

Comment: The problem is that,
The file is recognizing .php file
And a good evidence that when i type echo $_POST['get_option'];
i get the value of the $_POST
but when i make variable like this
$city = $_POST['get_option']
echo $city;
I get an error

Comment: Totally lost you there

Comment: Any other ideas yet ?

Answer (score 2):

check your ht-access file and replace your local URL to your live URL in database

Comment: Post your solution as answer, if that solution is not answered by someone already and mark your answer as the best solution so other in future may find it useful.

Comment: @Junaid done.
I only had to wait 2 days to mark it as the best answer.

T